# Google play services version conflict in app with third-party library

Tags: android, google-play-services, version, build-error

I used third party [library (.jar)](https://github.com/stqry/TriceKit-Android-SDK) which has dependencies on **play-services:6.5.87** and my main app module use **play-services-gcm:8.3.0** which is latest version. Both upgrading to **8.+** from **6.+** and downgrading from **8.+** to **6.+** doesn't work and have build error.

Please do comment if you find my question confused, i will try provide detail explanation as much as i can . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After couples hours of googling , i figured out to run successfully. Google has made update on **google-play-services** api in **8.+** and remove some of the impl which they once had in **6.+** but 7.+ don't. See here for play service api [release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) . Since third party library use **google location service**.My app has depend on new impl of **GCM ( 8.+)** . Changing version to **7.8.0** esp solve my issue .

Things learned here is if you don't neccessary have to depend on third party which use seperate google-play-service, don't waste time on that. Otherwise use alternative library. Beacause the only way you solve this prob is , ask library supporter to build (.aar) version with latest **google-play-servies**. If not you may fall into the same issue I did.

Hopt it helps

Answer (score 1):

check your build.gradle file and android build version.

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'//updated version you can put
and check android build version you installed.

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'//updated version you can put.
or

```
go file->project structure-> dependency tab -> add Library dependency(available google play services)
```

Comment: current android build version is **buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"** . are you saying that simple put 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0' , 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0' in gradle ?

Comment: or go file->project structure-> dependency tab -> add Library dependency(available google play services)